# ActionLink doesn't make correct with URL, but RouteLink does with attribute routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I occasionally have `ActionLink` refuse to make the correct URL with placeholders in my application, but when I specify a `Name` on the `Route` attribute, it generates the URL property.

My most recent run in with this, is from this:

```
[RoutePrefix("RuleConfiguration")]
public class RuleConfigurationController : EntityController<RuleConfigurationModel, RuleConfiguration>
{
    //...Snip...
    [Route("{configurationId}/Edit", Name = "RuleConfigurationEdit")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int configurationId)
    {
        return View(...);
    }
    //...Snip...
}
```

Given this setup, I expect `ActionLink`, when used like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(name, "Edit", "RuleConfiguration", new { configurationId = conf.Id })
```

To give me a url along the lines of `/RuleConfiguration/1/Edit`. However, I get just`/RuleConfiguration`. When using `RouteLink` like so:

```
@Html.RouteLink(conf.Name, "RuleConfigurationEdit", new { configurationId = conf.Id })
```

This produces the expected URL. On this same view, I have an `ActionLink` generating a link to another action, and that one generates with the expected action name. The one difference is that this other action does not have any route parameters.

I've checked (several times) that I have the parameters passed `ActionLink` spelled correctly, and that the URL parameter matches what the function expects. The `Name` parameter to the `Route` was added to see if `RouteLink` would work, `ActionLink` did not work as expected before or after.

Is there something utterly boneheaded I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

Starting with the first view snippet:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    name,
    "Edit",
    "RuleConfiguration",
    new {
        configurationId = conf.Id
    }
)
```

This snippet uses [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) overload of the [`ActionLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    String linkText,
    String actionName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

This results in the following HTML:

```html
<a configurationId="1" href="">Hoge</a>
```

The `configurationId` attribute is added to the element because the last parameter is the `htmlAttributes` parameter.

I found that if the current request has been routed through `RuleConfigurationController`, simply calling the following *seems* to work fine (using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492936%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) overload):

```
@Html.ActionLink(name, "Edit", new { configurationId = 1 })
```

This results in the following HTML:

```html
<a href="/RuleConfiguration/1/Edit">Fuga</a>
```

However, this doesn't seem to work when attempting to reference an action in a different controller.

---

To use the overload with the parameters which you *intended* to provide, use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) one:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    String linkText,
    String actionName,
    String controllerName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

It's fine to pass `null` for the `htmlAttributes` parameter if you're not using it, making your snippet become:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    name,
    "Edit",
    "RuleConfiguration",
    new {
        configurationId = conf.Id
    },
    null
)
```

This produces the expected anchor element, and because the controller name is specified, it also works when referencing a controller through which the current request was not routed.